# How to forward traffic for specific IP over an tun0 interface

Tags: linux, iptables

I have a CentOS 7 box where there is tun0 interface. I want to forward traffic to a specific IP, originating from within the box, to go over the tun0.

I tried doing this

```
route add -host 12.12.12.12 dev tun0
```

also tried adding

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 2):

What you're wanting is called [*policy routing* (or *rule-based routing*)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ip-rule.8.html), where the routing process looks at something other than the destination (in addition to the destination) for its decision-making. This can be done with [`ip` using the `rule` command](http://www.allgoodbits.org/articles/view/24):

```
# echo '1 tunroute' >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
# ip rule add from 12.12.12.12/24 table tunroute
# ip route add default via {tun0-address} dev tun0 table tunroute
```

You only need to run the first command once, as it establishes an alias; technically, you don't need it if you only want to use table numbers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was not aware of this. However, it is still not working or the traffic is not reaching the destination. When I do the tcpdump on the tun0 interface, I see the message being send to the interface, but no response. Not sure what is the issue

Comment: Does the other side have its routes set up correctly? As well, are there any firewall rules preventing input traffic?

Comment: Note that `{tun0-address}` is the "remote address" for `tun0`, and not its own address.